# Do I need mysql installed in the same machine to use mysql2 gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Here's the scenario.

There are 3 boxes.

1. My dev box (box1) with mysql. Mysql2 gem installs just fine and database used is on the local box, box1 itself.
2. My prod box (box2) doesn't have mysql. Mysql2 gem won't install. I don't have mysql installed on this box because ...
3. My database box (box3) has mysql. I have host address, username and password for this box. box3 has the database that will work with box2.

Question

Do I need mysql installed on box2 to install mysql2 gem, even though I am not going to be using mysql database on box2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the MySQL client library and client development headers (usually libmysqlclient and libmysqlclient-dev or something similar). The server doesn't need to be installed or running.